# Vaadin new Table creates 2 separate tables

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

I am working on a legacy application which uses Vaadin, which is uses Google web tools internally)

I found that the tables in the mark up where created using multiple tables where one table would do. I set up a blank Vaadin project and found the same thing:

using this code:

```
//import com.vaadin.ui.Table;
final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

layout.setMargin(true);
setContent(layout);

Table table = new Table("The Brightest Stars");

table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
table.addContainerProperty("Mag", Float.class, null);

table.addItem(new Object[] { "Canopus", -0.72f }, 2);
table.addItem(new Object[] { "Arcturus", -0.04f }, 3);
table.addItem(new Object[] { "Alpha Centauri", -0.01f }, 4);

table.setPageLength(table.size());

layout.addComponent(table);
```

a table is rendered on the front end:

[image]

However when you look at the mark up, vaadin has created a separate table just for the headings (rather then use a 'th' element in the table.)

[image]

This seems a crazy thing to do. I'd say this was a bug, but from the vaadin doc's etc, this is correct behavior. Is there any way to disable this??

Comment: I'm not familiar with vaadin, is Table a widget from vaadin or gwt framework?

Comment: it's from vaadin. in the soure it mentions that the cells are limited by 'The current GWT implementation' however doesn't go into details. Looking at the docs for ScrollTable in GWT tables headers are done with a new/seperate table. so maybe this issue if from GWT rather then vaadin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

[image: Scroll Table]

If you look at this table, you can see there is a scroll within the table, not the whole grid, making the headers fixed. This way, the cell header stay on top the whole time.

This is a common use case, I remember implementing to a custom widget and reached a similiar solution to achieve this feature.

I never tried to use Vaadin, but looking up the source of `vaadin.ui.Table` there is some render modes to the column.  Sorry for not being that helpful.

`setColumnHeaders(String[] columnHeaders)` [Javadoc](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin/7.0.0.alpha3/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#setColumnHeaders(java.lang.String[])%22Javadoc%22)

Comment: Exactly like André said. Works like coded. In many typical Vaadin applications (business applications) Table is in a central row and column headers are essential to be visible all the time. You can disable this feature with setPageLenght(0), but it doesn't change the DOM structure.

Imlementing Table with very basic html table element syntax sure would be easy.

Comment: The issues I was having was with header columns and body columns becoming misaligned (esp when resizing), however this seems to be the way Vaadin intended it. so I guess technically this is the answer in accordance with Vaadin's implementation

Comment: You should create another question with this bug. This doesn't look "as intended". Attach to this question a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)